# Grafana panel threshold background color default

Tags: grafana

I work on a team where some people like the light grafana theme and some people like the dark grafana theme.

We have lots of panels that were written for a light grafana theme and leverage thresholds to indicate if a metric has gone sour. Unfortunately we can't figure out how to set the base threshold background color to the default background color of the theme (dark/light). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use transparent colour:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Last 0 is alpha value, which indicates how opaque each pixel is. 0 = transparent = theme colour will be used.